# Is silverlight 3.0 supported on a windows 2000 Box?

Tags: silverlight, windows-server-2000

I've got a client with pretty old boxes which want to be sure our still-to-be-coded Silverlight-based solution will work on windows 2000 / IE6

Anyone with experience on this scheme?

Thanks

Comment: To be honest, you would be doing your clients a favor by insisting that they upgrade.

Comment: I know that, but I doubt he will listen until these old boxes begin to produce too much smoke to see through. If it ain't broken, why would you change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes .. you are okay.

[See here](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx)

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: The updated link has the note "** Silverlight 2, 3 Only" so the answer is correct.

Comment: Sweet as, +1 for the updated link and original comment removed :)